# jQuery get value from input field's data-price parameter and create a new element out of it?

Tags: jquery

Ok, I'm a bit puzzled, as I can't find any examples of how to do this...

Let's say I have a few radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="product[]" data-price="19.95" />
<input type="radio" value="2" name="product[]" data-price="29.95" />
...
```

How can I extract the value from "data-price" parameter for each one of those and append a new element right next to each input field showing that value/price?

Sort of, assume I don't have a complete control over how the form and its elements are formed, and the price doesn't show up nicely/properly on the front-end, so I want to extract it from the input/radio field instead and show it next to it, properly formatted and all, all done dynamically.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(':radio[data-price]').each(function() {
    $(this).after('<span>Price:' + $(this).data('price') + '</span>');
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through all radio button using `each()` and add an element after it using `after()` method like following.

```js
$(':radio[data-price]').each(function() {
    $(this).after('<span>Price: ' + $(this).data('price') + '</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="product[]" data-price="19.95" />
<input type="radio" value="2" name="product[]" data-price="29.95" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('input:radio').each(function(){//iterate over each radio
var price = $(this).data('price');//get data-price of each rad io
$(this).after('<label>'+price+'</label>')//insert label after each radio

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="product[]" data-price="19.95" />
<input type="radio" value="2" name="product[]" data-price="29.95" />
```

Check this.
use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to get each radio

> Description: Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to append new label

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements

Answer (score 1):

Try this : iterate over all radio buttons and create a label using `data-price` and put it after the radio button, see below code

```js
$(function(){
  $('input:radio').each(function(){
    $(this).after('<label>' + $(this).data('price') + '</label>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="product[]" data-price="19.95" />
<input type="radio" value="2" name="product[]" data-price="29.95" />
```